# Atrribute from nested relations is not read in serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm now using DRF as a backend of my project.

i have product model like this

```
class product(models.Model):
     product_name = models.CharField(max_length=160)
```

i have category model like this

```
class category(models.Model):
      category_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
      category_icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='category)
```

because 1 product can have multiple category and a lot of image I create

```
class product_category(models.Model):
      product = models.ForeignKey(product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_collections')
      category = models.ForeignKey(category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='category_collections')
```

and the last model

```
class product_image(models.Model):
      product = models.ForeignKey(product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='image_collections')
      product_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='product')
```

Now I have Serializer like this

```
class ProductCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     category_name = serializers.CharField(source='category.category_name')
     class Meta:
         model = product_category
         fields = ('product_id','category_id','category_name')

class ProductImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = product_images
         fields = ('product_img',)

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     category_collections = CategoryProductSerializers(many=True)
     image_collections = ProductImageSerializer(many=True)
     class Meta:
          model = product
          fields = ('id','product_name','image_collections','category_collections')
```

From that serializer DRF will return
Error like this

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `category_collections` on serializer `ProductSerializer`.
> The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `product` instance.

but if i remove that category_collections field like this

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     # category_collections = CategoryProductSerializers(many=True)
     image_collections = ProductImageSerializer(many=True)
     class Meta:
          model = product
          fields = ('id','product_name','image_collections')
```

Everything is going fine, whats wrong with that categories collection, is my eye not seeing the mistake ?

Comment: You have typos in your code. Your naming is inconsistent. You declare model **product_image** and then in your **ProductImageSerializer** you're using the model **proruct_images** (*plural*), not  **proruct_image** as declared.  Also your serializer, the code of which you didn't publish, is named **CategoryProductSerializers** (with *s* - plural) while it's possibly just **CategoryProductSerializer** (without final *s*). Please edit your code and post the missing serializer.